# How to get out of thicker wetsuits efficiently and quickly?

Tags: scuba-diving, water-sports, surfing, wetsuits

I've always had a problem getting out of thicker wetsuits (4/3 mm and above, chestzip with/without hoodies). I would like advice from anyone who has tips getting out of these types of thick wetsuits (neoprene, Yulex, etc.), whether in dry or wet conditions (pre- or post- immersion into water). I tried to get out of one, and especially gripping and tugging the extremities firsthand, I still spent a lot of energy trying to just pull everything away from the torso. However, this was still when I was inside the house and not surfing.

I've been able to get out of this wetsuit wet, but it has always been a long, arduous process and quite a struggle. Recently, it's much more difficult due to a shoulder injury and less grip strength due to carpal tunnel/impinged nerves.

Is there any good way to effectively get out of these thicker wetsuits under wet or dry conditions, without feeling like Venom trying to rip out of the symbiote from the cartoons?

Comment: I've heard, but not tested, that women's nylon pantyhose (tights) works well.

Comment: Chest zip is actually harder than back zip due to the contortions required.

Comment: Great question - I've seen people properly injure thumbs removing neoprene socks.

Answer (score 1):

In the Falklands, because the water is so cold as it comes up off the Antarctic peninsula, I always wore 6mm wetsuits even for kayaking. The two solutions we used were:

- talc. Yes, it gets wet, but really helps with seals round wrists and ankles
- a friend and solidly rooted poles or bars. Much easier to peel someone else out of a thick wetsuit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm wondering if I am surfing by myself, what's a good way to get out of them?